# MinGW Debugger in VS Code is Stuck at Building tasks. What can I do to get it back to normal? I

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, mingw-w64

Earlier it used to  create the .exe files whenever I hit the F5 button to debug the code. But now for some reason I am unable to get it right and I messed up with the .json files, and it keeps throwing errors.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-Wall",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wpedantic"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the tasks.json file.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        

        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the launch .json file.

Comment: Please show the errors.